# Extract Office Open XML Cell containing date value in certain language using Linux perl program

Tags: xml, perl

I am trying to read an Excel file (2007+ format which is a zip file containing a bunch of xml files) containing dates using perl.

I can extract the date information in the defined format
by analysing a given xml sheet file sheet(x).xml (x=1,2,3,...,n) along with the file styles.xml where the date formats are stored.

However, the problem I am having is related to a specific
type of date format. The dates I am reading contain day and month names and this is where I have the problem. I cannot find any information in any of the internal xml files that tells me which
language the file has been saved in. Thus I cannot read/reproduce the date format with the given month and day value in the required language with my perl program that is shown in Excel!

So, is there any way I can determine the language that the Excel file was saved in or perhaps another way to reproduce the values I see in Excel with my perl program?

Using a French version of Excel I have noticed the following formats saved in the style.xml file of an Excel file I am analysing:

```
<numFmt numFmtId="171" formatCode="[$-F400]h:mm:ss\ AM/PM"/>

<numFmt numFmtId="176" formatCode="[$-809]dd\ mmmm\ yyyy;@"/>
```

The associated, formatted cell entries are:

dimanche 1 janvier 1900

01 January 1900

So, is the code for the country somewhere in the values "[$-F400]"  and "[$-809]" ? And, if so, is there a list of these codes along with their associates country values somewhere within
the Open XML file format definitions? I have scanned the document

Ecma Office Open XML Part 1 - Fundamentals And Markup Language Reference With ANt bookmarks 1

but found no information

Comment: What is the file type (extension) of the file? See also [Spreadsheet::ParseExcel](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::ParseExcel) and [Spreadsheet::Reader::ExcelXML](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::Reader::ExcelXML)

Comment: Thanks for the info. File extension is .xlsx, .xlsm etc. Should have mentioned that I have already looked at these perl modules and, unfortunately, neither solve my problem.

Comment: Can you post a link to a sample excel file? Also update your post with the Perl code you used.

Comment: If the excel files are set up correctly, your date fields are not stored as formatted values. They use number of days since 1900-01-00. Take Håkons advice and use S::R::ExcelXML. Then ask again if you have problems with that.

Comment: Thanks, but I have no problems with dates of the form dd-mm-yyyy etc. My problems are with dates of the form Tuesday 2 June 2020 i.e. dates that contain month and/or day NAMES. The formats for these (stored in internal XML file styles.xml) look like the ones I referenced in my initial question. Then depending on which language the Excel file has been created with, the result could be displayed in Excel as: Tuesday 2 June 2020 OR Mardi 2 Juin 2020. However, the perl module Spreadsheet::ParseExcel ALWAYS interprets these dates into English so the result will ALWAYS be Tuesday 2 June 2020.